# How to access matrix table value in python

Tags: python

How can we access the value of a matrix in Python, if I pass its column and row name as input in Python code.

For Example - If I input `A` as column and `B` as row, then from the matrix table, I should get its A and B map value.

So far I tried this code, but I was unable to figure out how to get its value:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
  
input1= 'B'
input2= 'B'

numpyArray = np.array([[5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2],  
                        [4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
                        [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
                        [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]) 
  
panda_df = pd.DataFrame(data=numpyArray, index=["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
                                         columns=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"])

print(panda_df)
```

Also, is it possible to achieve this solution in python 2.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of your created dataframe, just [select according to the inputs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-label):

```
panda_df[input1][input2]
```

But you can avoid the dataframe creation by creating a translation from letters to indexes using [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) (assuming the inputs will always be capitalized letters, starting from `A`):

```py
def letter_to_i(letter):
    """
    A -> 0, B -> 1, ...
    """
    return ord(letter) - ord('A')
```

And now [index the array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) directly:

```
numpyArray[letter_to_i(input1)][letter_to_i(input2)]
```

Comment: Thank you @Tomerikoo, is it possible to achieve this problem in python 2.7 with the use of dictionary or something else ?

Comment: What do you mean? As far as I can tell this should work as well in Python 2 (didn't test). I didn't understand what the dict has to do with anything

Comment: Thank you @Tomerikoo, yes its working fine, let me test this one in 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable name of the dataframe. This is for `python-3.x`.

For your case `panda_df`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> input1 = 'B'
>>> input2 = 'B'
>>> numpyArray = np.array([[5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2],  
...                         [4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1],
...                         [3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1],
...                         [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]) 
>>> panda_df = pd.DataFrame(data = numpyArray,  index = ["A","B","C","D"],columns = ["A", "B","C","D","E","F"])           
>>> panda_df
   A  B  C  D  E  F
A  5  4  3  3  2  2
B  4  3  2  3  2  1
C  3  3  1  2  1  1
D  2  2  1  1  1  1
>>> pd.DataFrame(panda_df[input1],index=[input2]) # to access one element
   B
B  3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @etch_45, No, the value should come 3 if we enter B in input1 and B in input2.

Comment: @ED0268 use `pd.DataFrame(panda_df[input1],index=[input2])`

Comment: Thank you @etch_45, let me test this solution.

Answer (score 0):

To access cell value

For python 3.0+ use:

```
panda_df.at[input1, input2]
```

For python 2.7 use:

```
panda_df.ix[input1, input2]
```

Comment: Can you replicate that solution in python 2.7 as per my above code.